# Python SMTP server on Mac

Tags: python, macos, flask

I am trying to run a test python smtp server on Mac.

I use the following script in `venv` but nothing happens. I need to hit ctrl C to bring back the prompt.

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

I have tried a few other ports 8025 and 25.On 25 I get an error `socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

-----------UPDATE------
Using @petrubear suggestion below, still getting the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratchmail.py", line 10, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1:2525')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I was expecting some form of response in the terminal. Not unlike if I start a flask server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't see anything on the screen when the server starts, but try sending an email and you should see the message on the console like this:

```py
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:2525
```

```
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============5184031310585311106=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: emg1@test.com
To: emmg2@test.com
Subject: SUBJECT OF THE MAIL
X-Peer: 127.0.0.1

--===============5184031310585311106==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<body>
    YOUR MESSAGE HERE
</body>
--===============5184031310585311106==--
------------ END MESSAGE ------------
```

I wrote a script to send an email to the server I just started, like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_addr = 'sender@mail.com'
to_addr = 'target@mail.com'
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'smtp test'
msg.attach(MIMEText("email body", 'plain'))
server = smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1:2525')
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, am new to this but when you say send an email, how do you mean exactly? I was planning on using a simple flask_mail application to test this. But that gives me a Errno 61 connection refused error

Comment: I've updated my response with an example of how I sent the mail

Comment: Thanks but even using this am getting the same error. 

Have added the error log to the post above.

Comment: make sure you modify the example code smtplib.SMTP('127.0.0.1:2525') to the port you are using when starting the server python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer 127.0.0.1:2525

Comment: also, once you start the server, make sure it is running with the command netstat -na | grep 2525 (where 2525 is the port you are starting the server on)

Comment: Okay so I can get this to work  if I start the server outside of a `venv`. I am not sure why but this solves my problem for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I can get this to work if I start the server outside of a `venv`. I am not sure why but my solves problem for now.